# Should ToString be used for critical information?

Tags: c#, .net, framework-design

I just came across some code that overrides `ToString()` and returns some critical information (not just debug information).  Users of this type called `ToString()` and parse that critical data.

My opinion, from reading various bits and pieces over the years, is that `ToString()` has a rather weak `contract`, i.e. override it (*if you want*) to **display** some meaningful stuff.

See I said **display** there?  The code that I came across relied on the textual representation of instances of this type to be very specific;  adding anything other than what's expected would cause all sorts of problems.

So, my question is, if the textual representation of an object is critical, should `ToString()` be used or should a more explicit method/property be used, e.g. `AsText`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I share your concern. [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) states that the `ToString()` method

> [...] converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display.

[Oracle's documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for Java's `Object.toString()` is even little stronger:

> The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

I see these as strong indication that `ToString()` should convey information that is convenient for humans. A method that returns data that is to manipulated by other parts of the application should have a more informative name. In my opinion even `AsText()` is too generic.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a pretty bad plan. If users of the type need data, then that type should expose methods to return that data. Why are people parsing the string representation of an object *when they have access to the object*?

There are of course serialization scenarios, but those are well-defined, and rarely use `.ToString()` to do their job.

If the textual representation of a string for non-output purposes is required, then I would prefer a separate method (that may or may not utilize `ToString()` to do its job.) This helps consumers as well as implementors; it would be really unfortunate if a new coder wanted to add some debug dump info in `ToString()` and broke the class's consumers.

**UPDATE**: As MattDavey points out, if you implement `IFormattable`, then that's a good compromise: your consumers call `ToString()`, but with specific formats in mind, and reliable contract of what that means. Still different from what your colleagues are doing, but an option that's maybe more amenable to them.

Comment: I agree completely but would argue that the ToString method can be a good candidate to output textual data as long as your object implements IFormattable. There are various data binding frameworks out there that would work much nicer with IFormattable.ToString than with MyCustomTextOutputMethod().. but that's not to say you couldn't have both :)

Comment: @MattDavey Fair point, though that's a lot different than just overriding the standard `ToString()` method. I'll update to address that, though.

Comment: Yeah it's important to emphasize the distinction between the two methods. What I like about IFormattable is that in the standard implementation pattern your Object.ToString defers to IFormattable.ToString("G"), which gives you a nice progression path :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a definite answer.

I would argue for the case of using `ToString()`, because when creating an API in .NET it is appreciated when common naming conventions in .NET are used, instead of using less familiar names such as `AsText()`.
This convention is followed for example by the class `StringBuilder`, as its `ToString()` is returning critical information.

Comment: Agreed, same scenario applies for System.IO.StringWriter. It seems that when the objects sole purpose is to produce strings, using the ToString method is a sensible way to expose the end-result.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

To be more explicit, i would create different method for different format.

Ex:  toJson() -> JSON representation of the object
     toXML() -> XML representation of the object.
...etc

Note: there is probably a Library that does that for you.. in java there is. dont know in c#

As you say, parsing a toString() might lead to problem over time, since a new developer might not know that the toString() have a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `ToString()` after all is a method that we can use it in any **desirable** way, for instance `5.ToString()` convert the int to string and return it no matter if it was to use for display or not, on the contrary, in many situations we are **rely** on that info that is returned from `int.ToString()` to do further operations.

Answer (score 0):

No question, there is no definite answer to your question. In my opinion methods like `ToString` or `AsText` should only be used to provide the *internal* state of an object, e.g. to log it. In an object oriented language functional aspects should be derived by using a well defined interface, e.g. `GetOrderId`, `GetUserName`.

Answer (score 0):

No, I would not do that.  For example, if I had a person object, `ToString()` might return `this.firstname + " " + this.lastname.`  It's using it for automatic display purposes, like adding items to a list box. When the object is added, the person's name is displayed.  I don't think I would put critical or senstive information in the override.

Comment: One exception to this rule would be if the object implemented IFormattable, in which case the ToString method becomes a lot more flexible and powerful to expose data like this...